# Installing Full Text Search on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to install Full Text Search on 3 different SQL Servers, all 3 have many active databases running. Does the SQL server instance require downtime while I install this or can users continue using the databases while this is installing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're gonna have some downtime.

The installation not only requires the SQL Server service to be stopped but also **stops the service without asking** during installation. I was curious about your question and tested installing it in my lab environment.

- SQL Server version used on the test:

  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
      Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
      Express Edition (64-bit)

[image: Event viewer]

The need to stop SQL Server service might be related to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017):

> In SQL Server 2008 and later versions, the Full-Text Engine resides in
>   the SQL Server process, rather than in a separate service. Integrating
>   the Full-Text Engine into the Database Engine improved full-text
>   manageability, optimization of mixed query, and overall performance.